Unable to navigate to Quote screen from the SignIn screen using React navigation
I have 2 screens currently and my directory structure looks like this:
/views
/Quote

  Quote.js

SignIn.js

App.js
I have defined my App.js which looks like the following:
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import SignIn from './views/Signin';
import Quote from './views/Quote/Quote';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="SignIn">
        <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignIn} options={{headerShown:false}} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Quote" component={Quote} options={{title:"Atlas Insurance Limited"}} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
export default App

My SignIn.js is:
import React from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';

const SignIn = ({ navigation }) => {
  const handleSignIn = () => {
    console.log('Sign In button pressed'); // Debugging log
    navigation.navigate('Quote'); // Ensure this matches the name in the stack navigator
  };

  return (
    <View>
      {/* Your sign-in form and logic */}
      <Button title="Sign In" onPress={handleSignIn} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default SignIn;

I am still getting the following error:
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name": "Quote"} was not handled by any navigator.
Do you have a screen named 'Quote'?
I am following the documentation exactly but I am unable to resolve this error.

Resetting the metro cache resolved this error
